# How to get closest double value with datagridview in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, math, datagridview

I have a datagirdview that shows time and speed information from gps. I wanted datagridview shows data for each 10 times of speed and time shows elapsed time. I mean;

`speed     time
   10      0,31
   20      0,75
   30      0,95
   ..      ..`

However I faced some problems such as I can't always get value as clear as I thought. For example if I want to see speed and time in datagridview from 20 to 60 as speed. It shows;

`speed     time
   10      0,31
   20      0,75
   40      0,95
   60      1.25`

It missed some values as you see above(values for 30 and 50 are absent). To solve this I want to get nearest value(the next data) to my conditions.

Let me show you my data and what I wanted;

this is data
`speed     time 
   10      0,31
   13      0,35 
   16      0,40
   19      0,45
   22      0,48
   25      0,51
   28      0,54
   31      0,58
   34      0,62
   ..      ..`

this is what I want to see

`speed    time
  10      0,31
  22      0,48
  31      0,62`

Is there any function to to this?

EDIT
I collected data in listboxes(listboxvelocity and listboxtime), label1 shows speed, label2 shows elapsed time, and I get data from listboxes to datagridview. By the way I collect data by using timer, here is my code,

```
int p;
Stopwatch watch=new Stopwatch();

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      listBoxTime.Items.Add(label2.Text);
      listBoxVelocity.Items.Add(label1.Text);
      p = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
      watch.Start();
      var time = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
if (Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(label1.Text),0)%10==0 || 
    Convert.ToDecimal(label1.Text)==0)
  { 
       for (int i = 1; i < listBoxTime.Items.Count; i++)
           {
  dataGridView1.Rows[p].Cells[0].Value =listBoxVelocity.Items[i].ToString(); 
  dataGridView1.Rows[p].Cells[1].Value =  listBoxTime.Items[i].ToString();
           }
  }
```

**EDIT2**
I have two buttons to create artificial speed to simulate code.When I start to increase value of the label1(as speed) it catches the true value but it doesn't save it in datagridview1. Datagirdview1 always shows the lastest value which is the closest more than the last decade in its all rows. And here is the final code.

```
 private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        watch.Start();
        var time = watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        label2.Text = String.Format("{0:00.00}", time);
        List<DataPoint> liste = new List<DataPoint>();

       liste.Add(new DataPoint(Convert.ToDouble(label1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(label2.Text)));
      dataGridView1.DataSource = liste;
      List<DataPoint> newlist = new List<DataPoint>();
      for (int q = 10; q < liste.Max(t => t.Speed); q += 10)
     {
      newlist.AddRange(liste.Where(t => t.Speed % q == liste.Select(v => v.Speed % q).Min()).ToList());

      }
      dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
      dataGridView1.DataSource = newlist;
    }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           x += 3;
            aquaGauge1.Value =Convert.ToSingle(x);
            label1.Text = x.ToString();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {          
            x -= 3;
            aquaGauge1.Value = Convert.ToSingle(x);
            label1.Text = x.ToString();

    }
```

Comment: I hope you are collecting this data in a collection. If yes, then simply loop over the data and insert an entry into the DGV after a certain interval, say after every 3rd iteration

Comment: No, there is no build in function. You need to write it yourself. You could check for the min values of %10 this way you would get close to the round 10-ner numbers

Comment: I'm curious. How do you define the interval? I can't see any logic behind.

Comment: @Ben it looks like the closest number larger than 10, 20, ...

Comment: @MongZhu Thx :)

Comment: please provide the code that shows the way you store the data. Also a first attempt from you to solve it on your own would be good. Then people will see some effort, and help you.

Comment: I also use datagirdview instead of listboxes but I can't make it work.